# wlan0 gets an IP, but can't access the internet (or ping the router)

Tags: 12.10, wireless, networking, internet

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10. I can access the internet without problem at work via wi-fi, and I used to do that at home, but my internet provider changed my modem (which now has a native router) and things got a little bit weird.. I still can connect to my home network, my wlan0 interface gets an IP as it should, but I can't browse any websites or ping to any google servers; actually, I can't even ping my router.

With my phone and with another notebook (windows 7) I can access the internet via wi-fi without problems.

When I access the router with the windows note and browse the "Wireless Client List" tab, I don't see my linux notebook.

Here's some outputs:

netstat -rn

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 wlan0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 wlan0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 wlan0
```

ifconfig

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9c:2a:70:89:7a:59  
          inet addr:192.168.0.5  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::9e2a:70ff:fe89:7a59/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11328 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:13289 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:8270439 (8.2 MB)  TX bytes:2182573 (2.1 MB)
```

lspci -nn | grep 0280

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Can you ping another computer on the network? (Keep in mind that the Windows firewall may block pinging)

Comment: I can't, it says "Destination Host Unreachable", @Kupiakos

Comment: Hrm...strange. As a thought, is it possible to change your subnet to a 192.168.<nonzero> subnet? I've heard that can cause some funky  stuff to happen sometimes.